# Converting a numpy array into a dict of values mapped to rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, scipy

Consider that I have a 2D numpy array where each row represents a unique item and each column within the row represents a label assigned to this item. For example, a 10 x 25 array in this instance would represent 10 items, each of which have up to 25 labels each.

What would be most efficient way to convert this to a dict (or another appropriate datatype, bonus points if it can be sorted by length) that maps labels to the rows indices in which that label occurs? For example, `dict[1]` would return a list of the row indices that contain `1` as a label.

For example,

```
Given:
    [1, 2, 3]
    [1, 0, 0]
    [1, 3, 0]

Result:
    1: 0, 1, 2 # 1 occurs in rows 0, 1, 2
    3: 0, 2    # 3 occurs in rows 0, 2
    0: 1, 2    # 0 occurs in rows 1, 2 (0 is padding for lack of labels)
    2: 0       # 2 occurs in row 0 only
```

Comment: Please share some example data and expected output.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 Added a toy example

Comment: I believe result should have `2: 0` because 2 only occurs in the 0th row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`, before using `OrderedDict` to sort by number of observations:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict

A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [1, 0, 0],
              [1, 3, 0]])

d = defaultdict(list)

for idx, row in enumerate(A):
    for i in set(row):
        d[i].append(idx)

res = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True))

print(res)

OrderedDict([(1, [0, 1, 2]),
             (3, [0, 2]),
             (0, [1, 2]),
             (2, [0])])
```

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: added ordering by length.

We can use advanced indexing to create a grid indexed by items and labels.
We can then iterate over columns and use `flatnonzero` to get the item id's:

```
>>> ex = [[1, 2, 3],
...       [1, 0, 0],
...       [1, 3, 0]]
>>> 
>>> m = len(ex)
>>> n = np.max(ex) + 1
>>> grid = np.zeros((m, n), int) # could also use a smaller dtype here
>>> grid[np.arange(m)[:, None], ex] = 1
>>> grid
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1]])
>>> idx = np.argsort(np.count_nonzero(grid, 0))[::-1]
>>> dict(zip(idx, map(np.flatnonzero, grid.T[idx])))
{1: array([0, 1, 2]), 3: array([0, 2]), 0: array([1, 2]), 2: array([0])}
```

Note that dictionaries remember the insertion order of their keys. That is an implementation detail in 3.6 but will be a guaranteed feature in 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can just define a `{}` and iterate through the array, adding values in as you go, like so:

```
def f(array):
    table = {} # Initialize the dict
    for rownumber, row in enumerate(array): # Goes through all of the rows, with associated numbering
        for element in set(row): # Deduplicate to avoid duplicate row numbers
            if element not in table: table[element] = [] # Initialize empty row list if this element is new
            table[element].append(rownumber+1) # Add the current row number to the associated list of rows
    return d

print(f([[1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 0], [1, 3, 0]]))
```

This approach is **O(N<sup>2</sup>)**. This is achieved since set() is linear and is called **N** times. Also, set membership is constant time.